# value of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: json, android-studio, integer

I want to display a **high score** for my android from **JSON**. But I have error that said
`value 100 at HS of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject`

here is the JSON looks like

```
{
"HS": 100
}
```

here is my code to show the value of the JSON

```
public void getData(){
        AndroidNetworking.get("http://192.168.1.19/web_admin/public/api/highSkor_api")
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            //adding the product to product list
                            try {
                                //get JSON data
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("HS");
                                int HS = data.getInt("HS");
                                tx_hscore.setText(getString(R.string.high_score, HS);
                                Log.d(TAG, "ISI : "+HS);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        //Toast.makeText(Result.this, "High Score : "+data_highSkor.getHighSkor(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onError : "+ error);
                        Toast.makeText(Result.this, "Failed to reach server : "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: I tried to parse the JSON as `response.getInt("HS")` and for me it works fine. Are you sure that the error is at the same line. Can you post your stack trace.

Comment: @akhilnair whoops! sorry, I put the wrong code in my question.. I've edit it, this edited code should be my right code for my question. Sorry, 'cause I've just change it before write my question... By the way, if I use that code, my application would crash and get back to another layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("HS");
```

with

```
int hs = response.getInt("HS")
```

because `response` is already a `JSONObject`

if your json was like this

```
{
"HS": {
     "key1": "value1",
     "key2": "value2"
    }
 }
```

Then you could do

`JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("HS");`

Comment: Thanks for answering @akhilnair!.. I was trying to replace it like that, but why is my application crashed? everytime I'm trying to getInt from response directly, my application just crashed. It will go back to the previous page.

Comment: Can you please tell what the error you get?

Comment: I can't see the error. But in the locgat shows error like pid(and_some_numbers). That's what I remember. I'm trying to open my android studio right now, but my ram is just 4gb so, it still not responding :'') sorry.

Comment: I think its a different issue, but let me know the error when your studio is back.

Comment: my studio is back!.. I was trying to code like your answer (that what I code before I try the code in my question), and it works!! This is my bad, sorry. I just relized that I was write the getData() above the textView declaration. That's why my application was crashed. and when I try to code it again, and move the getData() after the textView declaration, it was succesfully runnning without any error :)

Comment: Always a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to write your `getData()` **after** the textView `tx_hscore` declaration.

and use this code in your `getData()` :

```
public void getData(){
        AndroidNetworking.get("http://192.168.1.19/web_admin/public/api/highSkor_api")
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            //adding the product to product list
                            try {
                                //get JSON data                                
                                int HS = response.getInt("HS");
                                tx_hscore.setText(getString(R.string.high_score, HS);
                                Log.d(TAG, "ISI : "+HS);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        //Toast.makeText(Result.this, "High Score : "+data_highSkor.getHighSkor(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onError : "+ error);
                        Toast.makeText(Result.this, "Failed to reach server : "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```